# Pentesting: Data boundaries for Strings

Tags: spring-boot, penetration-testing

One of the observations of a pen test is that there are no data boundaries. We have millions of fields in our applications. There are no validations on String type fields apart from occasional business logic related constraints on few fields.

The pen test has revealed issues related to a lot of String fields where one can insert numeric values or negative values and the app is processing the same without any issues.

My question is, is this a valid test? Why would someone disallow a numeric value such as “100” in a String field unless specifically asked for by business?
If this is a valid issue, this means every single String attribute has to be tested for non-numeric values which is quite insane. What should be the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late, but hopefully it's still helpful to you or someone else down the line.

This finding has to do with Input Validation, and is absolutely a valid test. This is one of the controls that is [recommended for implementation by the OWASP Foundation](https://owasp.org/www-project-proactive-controls/v3/en/c5-validate-inputs).

The risk here typically comes when this unsanitized value is passed to a downstream component, such as a database, user interface, or vulnerable function.

Here's a hasty example:

```
async function chargeUser(userId: number, currency: string) {
    const amount = (await User.getUser(userId)).amountDue;
    return await api.chargeUser(user.id, amount + currency);
}
```

The above Typescript function takes a user ID and currency, then makes a call to an API to charge the user for their current subscriptions. Let's make a few assumptions:

- The API expects the amount in the format of "100USD" or "100".
- The API allows negative charges for refunds.
- If the currency is not included, the API will assume USD.
- If the currency is unknown, the API call will fail with an error.
- The user currently has $100 due.

Under normal conditions, an employee would make a request from the UI, specifying the currency to charge the user in. They have no control over how much the user is charged:

```
{"userId": 1, "currency": "USD"}
```

This would result the user being charged 100 USD, as expected.

However, an attacker could leverage Javascript's loose typing and the lack of input validation to charge the user above the amount due:

```
{"userId": 1, "currency": 10000}
```

Since 100 + 10,000 is 10,100, and the API assumes the currency if it is omitted, this would result in the user being charged 10,100 USD.

Similarly, the attacker could instead do something such as:

```
{"userId": 1, "currency": -100100}
```

Since 100 - 100,1000 is -100,000 and the API supports negative amounts, this would result in the user having 100,000 USD deposited into their bank account.

Since penetration tests are time boxed and penetration testers generally don't have access to your backend code or possess the same level of in depth knowledge of your application as your team, it's not usually possible to determine each potential instance where this could occur, hence the broad recommendation to ensure proper input validation is implemented for all fields.

Any input from the user, for all fields, for all requests, [should always be validated to the fullest extent possible](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Since you have a large number of fields that share similar validation logic, you may wish to implement a single shared function responsible for validation, possibly according to a schema. For possible solutions, see:

- [Open API](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification)
- [GraphQL](https://graphql.org)
- [Spring Framework Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: That's a completely invalid "assumption" unless it's part of the business logic which is discussed way before implementation. We can also assume a million other things like a positive numeric value which "could" break the system or a perfectly valid String that "could" be invalid for downstream systems or even negative numbers in Strings which is expected on UI.

All of these "assumptions" falls under business logic and should not be part of pentest otherwise developers would spend the rest of their lives putting these non-sensical validations on every single field in the application.

Comment: Developers are humans, not machines, and do make mistakes. It’s possible for a developer to make an error as in the example above, or for a change in a downstream service to cause a similar situation. This is why security should always be implemented in a layered approach, and why input validation remains a recommendation by OWASP. Over the years, I have observed hundreds of apps implement proper input validation, and done so in my own applications as well. I stand by my assertion that input validation is important, a valid finding, and is possible to implement.

Comment: I will toss a caveat in here. Keeping in mind that I know nothing about your application, if these fields are data in, data out only (e.g. do not interact with any external services, are not used by the application in any way) and are properly stored, such as some sort of data ingress/aggregation API, it’s possible that input validation may be a mute point as you are suggesting here. However, my answer does not make this assumption, and instead reflects the limited information provided in your question and provides general guidance as it would be applicable to a majority of applications.